# Elementor Post Widget - get posts from another (multisite) blog id

Tags: wordpress, elementor

how to get posts in the elementor pro post widget from another blog-id? i tried with the custom query filter..

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/my_custom_filter', function( $query ) {

switch_to_blog(3);
$query->set( 'post_type', [ 'post'] );
```

} );

it works.. it shows me the posts from blog-id 3

BUT.. but all following widgets now also show posts from blog id 3!!! (including header, logo,..)

how is it possible to stop the query after the custom query filter.. like "restore_current_blog();" in this action?

Comment: After every instance of `switch_to_blog()` you need to call `restore_current_blog()` otherwise WP will think it is in a "switched" mode. - Read more about it here : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/restore_current_blog/

Comment: That being said, the filter you are setting up is the same as "pre_get_posts"  - so if you switch back in your filter, then you wouldn't get the posts from the other blog at all - So I have no idea how you could restore this.